# Find an equation of the quadratic function with zeros at $(0, 0)$ and $(6, 0)$ with $f(5) = -15$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, roots, conic-sections, quadratics

The Question is: write the equation of the quadratic function with zeros at $(0,0)$ and $(6,0)$ with $f(5) = -15$.

So, I know how to get the equation from the zeros, but I am confused with what I am supposed to do with "$f(5) = -15$".

Does it matter? I can do my own research, but have no idea what that is. ):

Thank you for any help :)

Sven Dysthe

Comment: A quadratic equation has the form $y=ax^2+bx+c$. Each of your three points gives you an $x$ and a $y$. Use them to solve for $a$, $b$ and $c$. Also, $f(5) = -15$ is just a sneaky way to say $(5,-15)$ is your third point.

Comment: Thanks John! This Is really helpful! I have a quiz tomorrow and was really confused. Could I just Google "How to make an equation from 3 roots?" Is that the same thing?

Comment: The function must have shape $a(x-0)(x-6)$. Use $f(5)=-15$ to find $a$.

Comment: Hmm... What? I'm sorry.

Comment: @SvenDysthe No. The roots are the zeros. Look at Andre Nicolas's solution above or ProbabilityGuy's solution below.

Comment: Suppose you know that $f(x)=a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$ for all $x$. Then what is $f(r_1)$? What is $f(r_2)$? What are the roots of $f$?

Answer (score 1):

You are given that the roots are $(0,0)$ and $(6,0)$. This means that if if $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c $, then you can write $f(0) = 0 $ and $f(6)=0$ you are also given $f(5)=-15$.

We have $f(0) = c = 0$. Hence, can write $f(x) = ax^2 + bx$. We still need to find $a$ and $b$. Since $f(6) = 0,$ we have $36a + 6b = 0 $. And since $f(5) = -15,$ then $25a + 5b = - 15 $ which means (after simplifying) $5a + b = -3$. Solve this for $b$ to obtain $b = -3 - 5a $. Substitute this into $36a + 6b = 0$, to obtain

$$ 36 a + 6(-3-5a) = 0 \implies 36a -18 - 30a = 0 \implies 6a = 18 \implies a = 3$$

and putting this into $b = -3-5a$, we obtain that $b = -3 -5(3) = - 18$. In other words, $\boxed{ f(x) = 3x^2 - 18x }$